# Objective-C: Any TreeSet or TreeDictionary?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, data-structures

Is there any analog in Objective-C to the TreeSet or TreeDictionary in Java. Basically, either a Set or Dictionary data structure that's implemented via a tree (sorted) versus a hash table (un-sorted).

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use TreeSet/TreeDictionary, when it's search time is `O(logN)` as opposed to the `O(1)` of the hash table?

Comment: Because a tree-based container enumerates its elements in a specific order, and a hash-based container enumerates its elements in random order.

Comment: Like I implied in the post, I need the data sorted.

Comment: You could just sort the `allValues` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of OS X 10.7 and iOS 5.0, you can use [`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  However, there is no `NSOrderedDictionary`.

`NSOrderedSet` orders the elements according to where you insert them, not according to a comparator function.  You can maintain sorted order efficiently by using `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` to find the index at which to insert a new object, with the `NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex` option.

Note also that although `NSOrderedSet` understands many of the same messages as both `NSSet` and `NSArray`, it is not a subclass of either.

Comment: In practice, an ordered dictionary is very easy to implement from an `NSOrderedSet` using a wrapper objects for values.

Answer (score 0):

iOS' high-level Foundation Framework doesn't have a tree-type collection, but there is one in CoreFoundation -  [CFTree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTreeRef/Reference/reference.html). There is no toll-free-bridged counterpart in Foundation with a nice object-orientated API, but it's better than nothing.